# Native Storage module with Ionic 3 Lazy loading

Tags: angular, ionic2, lazy-loading, ionic3

On my Ionic 3 app has around 10 pages and I have implemented lazy loading feature.Now I have a question where about the [**Native Storage module**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).Do I need to import it inside the `app.module.ts` file or is that ok if I'll import it each and every page's module? What is the recommended way of using it and of course the best practice?

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can see in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/), the recommended way to use the Storage is to add it to the `AppModule`:

> Next, add it to the imports list in your NgModule declaration (for
>   example, in src/app/app.module.ts):
>
> ```
> import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [
>     // ...
>   ],
>   imports: [      
>     BrowserModule,
>     IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
>     IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
>   ],
>   bootstrap: [IonicApp],
>   entryComponents: [
>     // ...
>   ],
>   providers: [
>     // ...
>   ]
> })
> export class AppModule {}
> ```

And then

> Finally, inject it into any of your components or pages:
>
> ```
> import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
>
> export class MyApp {
>   constructor(private storage: Storage) { }
>
>   ...
>
>   // set a key/value
>   storage.set('name', 'Max');
>
>   // Or to get a key/value pair
>   storage.get('age').then((val) => {
>     console.log('Your age is', val);
>   });
> }
> ```

If you don't want to do that, and prefer to add it to each page's module, a new instance of the Storage will be used for each module, but since the data is stored in the same place for the entire app, I guess the result would look like the same, but I'll recommend to add it to the `AppModule` from the `app.component.ts` in order to **use the same instance in the entire app**.

---

**UPDATE**

Just like you can see in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-a-service-provided-in-a-lazy-loaded-module-visible-only-to-that-module):

> **Why is a service provided in a lazy-loaded module visible only to that module?**
>
> Unlike providers of the modules loaded at launch, providers of
>   lazy-loaded modules are module-scoped.
>
> When the Angular router lazy-loads a module, **it creates a new
>   execution context. That context has its own injector, which is a
>   direct child of the application injector**.
>
> The router adds the lazy module's providers and the providers of its
>   imported modules to this child injector.
>
> **These providers are insulated from changes to application providers
>   with the same lookup token**. When the router creates a component within
>   the lazy-loaded context, Angular prefers service instances created
>   from these providers to the service instances of the application root
>   injector.

This may not be so easy to see when using the `Storage`, since the data is stored in the same place (storage engines underneath), but let's think that we want to inject a `StatusProvider` that contains a `public status: boolean` property inside of it.

**Since you're working with lazy-loaded modules (and each module has its own execution context)** if you include the `StatusProvider` in the `providers` array of the `AppModule` (in the `app.module.ts` file), the same instance of the `StatusProvider` will be used in the entire app. So if you change the `status` property somewhere in your app, and then another component from a different module tries to read the value, it will see the updated value, since the same instance is shared across the entire app.

Instead, if you add the `StatusProvider` in the `providers` array of each submodule, and again, since each submodule has its own execution context, each submodule will have its own copy of the `StatusProvider`. Therefore if you try to modify the `status` property inside of one submodule, that change won't be seen in other (lazy-loaded) submodules.

Comment: Here can you tell me what did you mean by the `same instance`? When we inject like this `constructor(private storage: Storage) { }` hope it'll create different instances of  `Storage` service for each component no?

Comment: I've edited (again) the answer, after taking a deep look at Angular docs. About your comment, please notice that when you do `constructor(private storage: Storage) { } ` you're not _creating_ an instance of the Storage, but _asking Angular to give you one instance of it_. So if there's an instance of that service already created, you'll get that one. That's why if you use a service to store the details of the products added to a cart, and you inject that service in several pages, all the pages can get the same information about the status of the cart.

Comment: At app.module.ts level you have a singleton instance. Whereas if you put it in the providers of the sub-module they create their own unique instances. So it's a one or many thing. So module 1 and 2 instances no longer share state in the non-singleton scenario

Comment: @JGFMK As far as I understand that happens only with lazy-load modules. Otherwise _A module can add providers to the application's root dependency injector, making those services available everywhere in the application._ ([doc](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#service-providers)). Providing services in a component would be scoped to that component only, but providing them in a _not lazy-loaded_ module will make them available across the entire app.

Comment: Yes  that concurs with my experiences.